# How can I listen to all inputs that have a "required" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, required

EDIT :

I have an input field and a checkbox. Checkbox allow to win "required" on this input field. I want to listen required, i mean if required is true or not. I don't want to listen checkbox.

==> When input win/lose required attribute, it trigger function (without use checkbox).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        cible_required_on = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.required_on');
        if(!cible_required_on.prop('required')){
            cible_required_on.attr("required", true);
        } else {
            cible_required_on.attr("required", false);
        }
    });


// Here my new function listening required attribute

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 changement_position_champ" id="bottom_left">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <label> Raison Sociale</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-use" ></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required_on" placeholder="Raison sociale"
                                   aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" ><p>Checkbox trigger required on input field</p></label>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(this).attr("required") or some variation?

Comment: Your code works, so I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Hi, nop it doesn't work

Comment: do you need validate that all input is required?

Comment: @vincent it clearly does: http://jsfiddle.net/gs90ano7/

Comment: I edited my post, hope people understand better what i want to do. Sorry if my instructions was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[required]').change(function(){
   alert('required')
});
```

```js
$('input[required]').change(function(){
   alert('required')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required/>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Code only answers without comments or an explanation fall under the category of low quality.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question the user requires to select the input with some conditions like it is the checkbox and is required. So instead of running a loop which is more memory eating, we can use the jquery filter selectors to achieve the goal.

Below is the example.

```js
var a = $('input[required][type="checkbox"]');
console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' required>
```

Comment: Please provide some details about how this fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing I'm late to the party, here's my contribution:

---

```js
// ES6 supported - () => {} , arrow-function
$(':input[required]').change((e) => {
 alert("Changed: " + e.target.value);
});

// Older compatibility
/*
$(':input[required]').change(function(e) {
 alert("Changed: " + e.target.value);
});
*/
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type something and unfocus from input.</p>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" required />
  <input type="text" required />
  <input type="checkbox" required />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: He did not specify anything about compatibility. `jQuery` supports `Internet Explorer: 9+`

Comment: If you're talking about arrow-functions, it's an easy fix.

Comment: Yes, it is. Nice answer.